# Sharing session by setting JSESSIONID cookie for multiple domains

Tags: java, session, tomcat, web-applications, servlets

I have web application part of which is accessible from www.domainA.com, another part is acessible from www.domainB.com. When I enter my App through domainA.com and than I navigate to domainB.com old session is lost and new sesion is created. But I wan't my session to be shared across these two domains (when I login on domainA.com I don't want to login again on domainB.com).

So I was thinking that solution would be to create `JSESSIONID` cookie for both domains domainA.com and domainB.com nomatter which site was entered.

I thought that I will create `HttpSessionListener` an set `JSESSIONID` cookie manualy on session creation. But I don't know how to set cookie from this HttpSessionListener.

Another way how to achieve this is by using `Filter`. But to me it seems uneccesary to filter each request even if I need to set cookie only on Session creation.

I'm using Tomcat 7 but general solution for all java servers would be appreciated.

I also thought that the best solution would be to somehow hook or override mechanism which sets cookie in normal situation an make it set this cookie for both domains.

Possibly there exists better and cleaner solution Which didn't think of.

Comment: If it were subdomains, it's matter of setting an attribute in a Tomcat XML config file.

Comment: So its Tomcat dependent? I cannot reach it from my App?

Comment: `JSESSIONID` is managed by container not by your webapp, so yes, its configuration is container dependent. You can however create another layer over it using a filter in your webapp, as you have answered yourself.

Comment: To my knowledge, new session could be started only by user accesing my web app. So this way I could get by just with HttpSessionListener. But I don't know how to access triggering request from this listener.

Comment: The session is not necessarily created and destroyed during a HTTP request (e.g. during server side session timeout there's no means of  a HTTP request at all), hence the HTTP request object reference is nowhere available. As said, use a filter. This doesn't cost 1 additional second on every request or so. It's at most 1ms.